# OpenCV hough lines vs scikit-image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, scikit-image

I've been comparing OpenCV and scikit-image's hough lines implementation and I'm finding that scikit-image gives significantly better results. I'm trying to do the same canny/hough lines transform in both (with the addition of a `GaussianBlur` in OpenCV as I believe scikit does that as part of canny).

I would like to understand how to get similar results from OpenCV as from scikit-image if possible.

Here is the result from scikit-image:

[image]

And here is the result from OpenCV:

[image]

You can see that they're significantly worse. The intermediate canny output from OpenCV is also worse, (but not to a huge degree), so I'm not sure if that's the problem?

I've uploaded the code and results to https://github.com/grokys/hough-test. Apologies for my python skills.

Comment: Although [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga8618180a5948286384e3b7ca02f6feeb) and [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#probabilistic-hough-line) seem to implement the same algorithm, how do you know they implemented it in the same / "right" way? `HoughLinesP` has parameters for the distance and angle resolution (which you explicitly set), `probabilistic_hough_line` only allows processing at certain angles (which you don't use). For a definitve answer, I'm afraid, you'll need to deep dive into the source codes.

Comment: Yeah they obviously don't implement them in exactly the same way, but I've tried looking at the source (tried, as OpenCV isn't exactly readable) and they _appear_ to be doing broadly the same thing. I was hoping to hear from someone more knowledgeable on such things, who maybe knows the difference and knows how to improve the OpenCV output.

Comment: how does scikit choose the parameters internally? Maybe you can try using identical parameters on an algorithm level?

Comment: What versions of OpenCV and scikit-learn are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The functions `HoughLinesP` and `probabilistic_hough_line` are equivalent in that they are meant to perform the same operation. However, the implementations are clearly quite different. This is evident from the fact that they have different arguments. The simple answer is, it is possible get the same result from either function if you provide the functions with equivalent arguments. It is not a problem with the functions or how they are implemented but rather with the arguments you are passing to them.